# Does DynamoDB query that returns an empty result set consume any capacity?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

If my query to DynamoDB table returns an empty result set, does it count to the provisioned capacity? If not, does that mean I can query as frequently as I want without being throttled as long as there's no record matching?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will still consume read throughput if there is an empty result set.

Relevant section from the [*Item Size Calculations* documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#CapacityUnitCalculations):

> If you perform a read operation on an item that does not exist, DynamoDB will still consume provisioned read throughput: A strongly consistent read request consumes one read capacity unit, while an eventually consistent read request consumes 0.5 of a read capacity unit.